# mongo get first data after sorting by descending

Tags: ruby, mongodb

how to get first data on mongo after sorting all data by desc. Example :

i'm using this tutorial in my app : [mongo for ruby](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver)

i'm typing this in my console :

```
client = Mongo::Client.new
db     = client['example-db']
coll   = db['example-collection']
collect_data = coll.sort("desc by created")
```

result from collect_data.count = 11

how to get first data from `collect_data` ?

need help, thanks master

Comment: limit the result to one.. done

Comment: i want get first data

Answer (score 0):

try

```
collect_data[0]
```

or

```
collect_data.to_a[0]
```